# Why does json schema validate json with missing properties

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I am using this json schema validator: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ to validate some json. It suprised me that it validates the schema even when a property is missing in the json.

Schema

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "properties": {
      "test": {
        "type": "array"
      }
    }
}
```

Should validate

```
{
    "test": []
}
```

Should not validate (but validates!)

```
{}
```

Why is this considered valid and how can I validate the json so that the property `test` must be part of the json?

Comment: You have to set "additionalProperties" to false

Comment: Thanks @Pedro, seems my question was not clear enough. Your comment helped me find the solution of using `required`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `required` attribute that can be done. It seems the validation uses `required: false` for all properties by default.

This validates and forces the property to be present:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "properties": {
      "test": {
        "type": "array"
      }
    },
    "required": ["test"]
}
```